# Calculate within nested list in R

Tags: r, list, dictionary, tibble

How do I calculate the sum of the count per city in nested lists and store it in a new tibble using map?

The output of the nested lists looks like this:

```
City:'s-Hertogenbosch`

$`'s-Hertogenbosch`$`5392`

$`'s-Hertogenbosch`$`5392`$men

 A tibble: 20 x 2

   age              count
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 0 tot 5 jaar        20
 2 5 tot 10 jaar       40
 3 10 tot 15 jaar      45
 4 15 tot 20 jaar      20
 5 20 tot 25 jaar      25


$`'s-Hertogenbosch`$`5392`$women
 A tibble: 20 x 2
   age              count
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 0 tot 5 jaar        15
 2 5 tot 10 jaar       30
 3 10 tot 15 jaar      35
 4 15 tot 20 jaar      30
 5 20 tot 25 jaar      15



City:'Aa en Hunze`
$`Aa en Hunze`
$`Aa en Hunze`$`9443`
$`Aa en Hunze`$`9443`$men
 A tibble: 20 x 2
   age              count
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 0 tot 5 jaar         0
 2 5 tot 10 jaar       10
 3 10 tot 15 jaar       5
 4 15 tot 20 jaar       5
 5 20 tot 25 jaar       5


$`Aa en Hunze`$`9443`$women
 A tibble: 20 x 2
   age              count
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 0 tot 5 jaar         5
 2 5 tot 10 jaar        5
 3 10 tot 15 jaar       5
 4 15 tot 20 jaar      10
 5 20 tot 25 jaar       5
```

I know how to store 1 specific postal code in a tibble:

```
sum of count <- tibble(sum(data[[1]][[1]][[1]]['count']))
```

But i can't figure out how to apply this for all lists in R using map:

```
Get_count_per_postal <- map_int(data, function(x){
    tibble(municipality = names(data), count_inhibitants = sum(data[[?]][[?]][[?]]['count']))
  })
```

I'm having a hard time accessing the nested lists and apply a calculation, it would be great if someone set me on right path.

Edit:

```
`8044` = list(men = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(110, 
85, 60, 45, 20, 65, 130, 80, 70, 45, 25, 15, 15, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), women = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(105, 
80, 55, 35, 30, 105, 120, 80, 50, 35, 25, 10, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), migration = c(western_migration_background = 120, 
non_western_migration_background = 195), households = c(single_households = 75, 
multi_person_households_without_kids = 130, multi_person_households_with_kids = 310
)), `8045` = list(men = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(0, 
0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), women = structure(list(
    age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", "5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", 
    "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", "25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", 
    "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", "45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", 
    "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", "65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", 
    "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", "85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", 
    "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), migration = c(western_migration_background = 0, 
non_western_migration_background = 0), households = c(single_households = 5, 
multi_person_households_without_kids = 5, multi_person_households_with_kids = 5
))))
```

[img of structure in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ekZF.png)

```
> dput(sample(data, 1))
list(Alblasserdam = list(`2951` = list(men = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(355, 
360, 305, 335, 265, 285, 300, 255, 270, 310, 315, 300, 250, 260, 
320, 235, 145, 85, 40, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), women = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(335, 
360, 295, 290, 270, 315, 285, 265, 305, 330, 345, 310, 265, 320, 
345, 320, 205, 170, 90, 20)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), migration = c(western_migration_background = 630, 
non_western_migration_background = 820), households = c(single_households = 1350, 
multi_person_households_without_kids = 1395, multi_person_households_with_kids = 1580
)), `2952` = list(men = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(30, 
35, 40, 40, 30, 20, 20, 25, 30, 45, 50, 30, 15, 20, 10, 10, 0, 
5, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), women = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(30, 
35, 40, 60, 25, 30, 25, 30, 35, 50, 40, 25, 25, 15, 10, 10, 5, 
5, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), migration = c(western_migration_background = 45, 
non_western_migration_background = 20), households = c(single_households = 70, 
multi_person_households_without_kids = 80, multi_person_households_with_kids = 175
)), `2953` = list(men = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(200, 
215, 200, 200, 175, 240, 200, 195, 180, 225, 275, 170, 125, 115, 
115, 85, 55, 25, 5, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), women = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(190, 
185, 215, 175, 175, 215, 190, 190, 210, 230, 215, 160, 120, 130, 
125, 120, 60, 30, 15, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), migration = c(western_migration_background = 510, 
non_western_migration_background = 600), households = c(single_households = 815, 
multi_person_households_without_kids = 650, multi_person_households_with_kids = 1010
)), `2954` = list(men = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(75, 
70, 105, 100, 115, 75, 50, 55, 85, 90, 120, 125, 125, 85, 60, 
25, 5, 5, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), women = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
"5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar", 
"25 tot 30 jaar", "30 tot 35 jaar", "35 tot 40 jaar", "40 tot 45 jaar", 
"45 tot 50 jaar", "50 tot 55 jaar", "55 tot 60 jaar", "60 tot 65 jaar", 
"65 tot 70 jaar", "70 tot 75 jaar", "75 tot 80 jaar", "80 tot 85 jaar", 
"85 tot 90 jaar", "90 tot 95 jaar", "95 jaar of ouder"), count = c(50, 
90, 90, 105, 100, 50, 60, 60, 75, 100, 150, 110, 100, 75, 60, 
20, 15, 5, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), migration = c(western_migration_background = 160, 
non_western_migration_background = 105), households = c(single_households = 180, 
multi_person_households_without_kids = 345, multi_person_households_with_kids = 475
))))
```

Kr,
Quido

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of the small example you showed so that it gives the structure correctly

Comment: Hi Akrun i added the dput like you asked. The question is how I can 'access'  the count variables and sum this up per municipality, via the map function.

Comment: your `dput` is giving me errors.  Can you post the full dput output on a small example

Comment: I editted the post with a new dput sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear clear about the structure correctly.  Perhaps, a recursive option would work - use `rrapply` to change the structure by `melt`ing the nested `list`, then `filter` the column 'L4' having only 'count', `unnest` the `list` column 'value', do a `group_by` `sum` (if we don't want to include 'L3' i.e. `sex` as grouping, remove it to get the overall count per 'municipality'

```
library(rrapply)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rrapply(data, how = 'melt') %>%
    filter(L4 == 'count') %>% 
    unnest(value) %>%
    group_by(municipality = L1, sex = L3) %>%
    summarise(count_inhabitants = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  municipality          sex   count_inhabitants
  <chr>                 <chr>             <dbl>
1 City:'Aa en Hunze     men                  25
2 City:'Aa en Hunze     women                30
3 City:'s-Hertogenbosch men                 150
4 City:'s-Hertogenbosch women               125
```

#### Update

Using the OP's data

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(data, ~ map_dfr(.x, ~ map_dfr(.x[c("men", "women")],
    ~ sum(.x$count, na.rm = TRUE), .id = 'sex'), .id = 'id'),
     .id = 'municipality')
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  municipality id      men women
  <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Alblasserdam 2951   5000  5440
2 Alblasserdam 2952    455   495
3 Alblasserdam 2953   3000  2950
4 Alblasserdam 2954   1370  1315
```

#### data

```
data <- list(`City:'s-Hertogenbosch` = list(`'s-Hertogenbosch$5392` = list(
    men = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", "5 tot 10 jaar", 
    "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar"), count = c(20, 
    40, 45, 20, 25)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -5L)), women = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
    "5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar"
    ), count = c(15, 30, 35, 30, 15)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L)))), `City:'Aa en Hunze` = list(
    `'Aa en Hunze$9443` = list(men = structure(list(age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", 
    "5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar"
    ), count = c(0, 10, 5, 5, 5)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L)), women = structure(list(
        age = c("0 tot 5 jaar", "5 tot 10 jaar", "10 tot 15 jaar", 
        "15 tot 20 jaar", "20 tot 25 jaar"), count = c(5, 5, 
        5, 10, 5)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L)))))
```

Comment: Thankyou akrun, for your reply, is this also possible within the map function>?

Comment: @QuidoW Based on the structure you showed, it is a nested list and `map` cannot go deeper in the nested list.  We may need to flatten the list and then use `map`, i.e. the reason I used `rrapply`

Comment: @QuidoW can you check the update.  I used only `map`